# How can we make use of query string in rewrite url using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Actually I have a url abcd.html which is getting rewritten to abcd.php using .htaccess=.

Now I am passing a query string like abcd.html?id=100 and I would like to rewrite it to abcd.php?id=100.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule abcd.html\?id=(\d+)   abcd.php?id=$1
```